# How does the apostrophe work (examples inside)?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

Which of this is correct?

1. Excels logo look like a book
2. Excel's logo look like a book

How does the apostrophe change the above sentences meaning?

Comment: Neither of them is grammatical, because the verb "look" doesn't go with the singular subject "logo". If you correct that, you get two different spellings for the same sentence: the second one happens to follow the rules of English writing, the first doesn't . Silly, isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement would be

> Excel's logo looks like a book.

An apostrophe is used to denote possession.
Since logo is a singular noun, `look` is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The second statement is correct.

> Excel's logo looks like a book.

This is because the logo belongs to Excel, that is why we say Excel's.